# Synonym for a Symmetric Bernoulli Trial?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am wondering if there are any technical or informal, simplified synonyms for a symmetric Bernoulli Trial, $B(1,p)$, where $p=q=(1-p)=0.5$?  The closest one I can think of is a "fair coin", or "un-biases coin", although I dislike it because it refers to one specific randomizing device.

Given how common this probability value is, and how the Bernoulli Trial is the basis of many discrete distributions, I imagine there is some other common-name for it.

Comment: Maybe Uniform Bernoulli Distribut(ion/ed).

Answer (score 1):

Uniformly distributed on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Yes, that is an equivalent representation, and it does exactly describe the $p=q=(1−p)=0.5$ condition. However, I intended the synonym to be a _simpler_ description. This has at least three parameters, possibly four: "Uniform", a=0, b=1, and "Discrete". The original description only has two parameters: "Bernoulli", and $p=0.5$.